# Command-line RESTful service invoker for Linux?

Tags: linux, web-services, rest, basic-authentication

Is there any sort of single-line command I could use on a Linux machine for invoking a web service over SSL using Basic Authentication?  It seems to me there should be, but my Google-fu seems to be lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is good enough. SSL and many auth types are supported.

Comment: I thought curl was a php thing.  Nice, that will work perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Mozilla Firefox extension HttpRquester is more easier: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/httprequester/